# Namesapce Nested Form Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am new to Ruby on rails and I’m messing around with forms.

Let’s start off with a bit of background around the projects I’m working. Long story short (dumbed-down version), it’s a question and answers website, where the user guesses the answer, the system checks if the user’s submission is correct or not, displays the appropriate message back, adds their points to the scoreboard, and stores the attempt to a DB table.

I have the submissions form being displayed on the questions page.

I know it’s a simple question, but I’m hoping someone can explain why, or how its happening so I can learn. I believe I am misunderstanding how the nested groups of namespaces are working with the different models and calling them correctly.

I have the following error:

**Namespace**: member

**Routes**

```
namespace :member do
  resources :challenges do
    resources :submissions
  end
end
```

**Models**

Submissions

```
class Member::Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :challenges
end
```

Challenge

```
class Member::Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :point
  has_many :submissions
```

Submissions Form

```
<%= form_for([@member_challenge, @member_challenge.submissions.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Submissions Controller

```
before_action :find_challenge 
def create
  @member_submission = @challenge.submissions.create(params[:submission].permit(:content))
  @member_submission.save  
end

....

private

def find_challenge
  @challenge = Member::Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
end
```

Error Being Recieved

```
NoMethodError in Member::Challenges#show

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/Cyberlympix/app/views/member/submissions/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `member_challenge_member_submissions_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004131b28>:0x0000000432a218>
Did you mean?  member_challenge_submissions_path
               member_challenge_submission_path
```

I know that its to do with the form, where I am calling the @member_challenge, But unsure what im doing wrong with it?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone able to lend a bit of advice??

Comment: When you create associations to namespaced models you need to specify the class name. `belongs_to :challenge, class_name: 'Member::Challenge'` otherwise it will attempt to use the table `challenges` and the model `::Challenge` (from the root namespace).

Comment: The error is because the [polymorphic route helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) are getting confused by the namespace and prepending it on both resources. I believe there is some workaround by overriding [model naming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html) which is used when figuring out helper names from model classes. https://coderwall.com/p/heed_q/rails-routing-and-namespaced-models